# Django pre_save signal

Tags: django, django-signals

I needed to be able to change my model data before it's saved, so I considered using pre_save handler to be the best option:

```
@receiver(pre_save, weak = False)
def pre_category_save(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['instance'].tags is None:
        kwargs['instance'].tags = kwargs['instance'].__unicode__().replace(' -> ', ', ')
```

Under the instance key of kwargs I expected to find the actual model instance I'm saving, but instead I got an object of LogEntry class - that's the cause why my function fails returning this error: 'LogEntry' object has no attribute 'tags'. So - how can I fix that? Checking if instance has attribute tags is not a solution, because I always get only logentry object. I can eventually overload Model.save method, though I'd rather not do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified the model class that's being received by this signal, so it's connected itself to *all* model saves - including LogEntry. Instead, do this:

```
 @receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel, weak=False)
 ...
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders).

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `sender`.