# Why pre_save signal doesn't work on other files besides the model file?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a `hook` for when i made a new `save()` on some model and for a reason that i don't understand the `receiver` method is not called if the decorated method is in another file.

I've a class called `Pizza` and i want to use the `pre_save` method from `django.db.models.signals` to perform a action before the content is saved

```py
# models.py file
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

```py
# actions.py file
from .models import Pizza
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Pizza)
def before_action(instance, **kwargs):
    logger.info("Before action method was called.")
```

The code above doesn't work unless i put the method `before_action` within the `Pizza` model like this:

```py
# models.py file

from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Pizza)
def before_action(instance, **kwargs):
    logger.info("Before action method was called.")
```

How can i split this 2 responsibilities on each file? i would like to keep all actions in a separated file

I've also tried to follow this answer but it didn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8022315/2336081

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to import the signals.

**my_app/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'

    def ready(self):
        import my_app.signals
```

**my_app/__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'my_app.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

Replacing `my_app` with the correct value. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115097/the-right-place-to-keep-my-signals-py-file-in-a-django-project/21612050#21612050) for more information.

Comment: it works, after creating the `ready` method there is no need to create the variable on `__ini__` file :)